# NSPredicate - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code= EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate

I'm trying to read a data from CoreData with multiple NSPredicates, but I'm getting `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code= EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

Here is the code where I try to read the data:

```
public class func fetchSetting(key: NSString, countryId: Int) -> Setting {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")

    var existingSetting: Setting?

    let keyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@", key)
    let countryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "countryId = %d", countryId)

    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [keyPredicate!, countryPredicate!])

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    if let fetchResults = CoreDataHelper().managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Setting] {
        if (!fetchResults.isEmpty && fetchResults.count > 0) {
            println(fetchResults.first!.value)
        } else {
            existingSetting = nil
        }
    } else {
        existingSetting = nil
    }

    return existingSetting!
}
```

And this is how I call this function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textColorSetting = SettingCoreData.fetchSetting("text_color", countryId: 3)
}
```

The error is at `keyPredicate` and `countryPredicate` declarations. I tried `key` parameter as both `String` and `NSString` but I don't thing that is the issue. I'm fairly new to swift and I couldn't really figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: Btw, you can simplify your predicate construction as `predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@ AND countryId == %d", key, countryId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often the case that `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is due to unwrapping a variable whose value is `nil`.
This is exactly what happens in your code when you `return existingSetting!`, since `existingSetting` is always going to be `nil` in your code (you're probably missing an assignment where you wrote `println(fetchResults.first!.value)`).

In order to fix this, you can change the function signature to return an optional `Setting`:

```
public class func fetchSetting(key: NSString, countryId: Int) -> Setting?
```

Then, at the end of the function, just return `existingSetting`, without unwrapping it with the exclamation mark.

```
return existingSetting
```

When you invoke the `fetchSetting` function from `viewDidLoad()`, you can then test if you have a non-`nil` value, by using the typical Swift construct `if let`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let textColorSetting = SettingCoreData.fetchSetting("text_color", countryId: 3) {
        // Do stuff with textColorSetting
    }
}
```

Comment: Given his existing code, `existingSetting` will always be nil.  I suspect he's missing an assignment near the line `println(fetchResults.first!.value)`  But functionally, he needs to be returning an optional as you suggest.

Comment: You're right, I missed that and I'll edit the answer right away, thanks! :)